# How to align content horizontally middle and fix to the left?

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I want to build a page so that all content is in the middle of the page. But as I resize the browser, the content goes to minus left and I cant even scroll it.

I want something like this: https://www.apple.com/au/mac/.

Here all content is in the middle and if I resize the browser to a smaller width then I can still scroll horizontally to see all content.

I have tried something similar but when I resize the browser, my content goes to the left beyond the left margin and I cant scroll to the left.

This is the code.

CSS:

```
html, body
    width: 100%; height: 100%;



main
    position: absolute; top:0; left: 0;
    width: 1000px; height: 100%;
    left: 50%;  margin-left: -500px;
    border: 1px solid;
```

Answer (score 0):

dont use position absolute. try this style for your main:

```
.main { margin: 0 auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jatin. I tried this and it worked!

html, body
    width: 1024px; height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;

main

```
position: relative;
background-color: grey;
```